# How to convert single output of microphone into multiple values for using fft?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio

i am trying to make a real time audio spectrum display.
My problem is microphone gives an single analog output, but to apply fft we need atleast 8 inputs to fft. how can i convert a single input from microphone to  atleast 8 values for using fft??????

Comment: Hi, welcome to signals.SE! Your question is very unclear. I think you're missing either the fact that your microphone gives you a voltage *signal* that changes over time, and hence, your soundcard gives you a *sequence* of numbers, which you then can process, or you're completely missing what you need the FFT for. In either case, you might want to look at what a soundcard does and what you're interested in in a little more depth before asking a less confused question!

Answer (score 1):

The FFT will process the samples bs time of your analog signal. For 8 consecutive samples in time from your sound file you will get 8 uniformly spaced frequency bins in your FFT ranging from DC up to 7/8 of your sampling rate, and each bin will have a frequency resolution of 1/T Hz where T is the time duration of your 8 samples. I think you will see from that, for your application, you will want a lot more samples (assuming you are interested in seeing more frequencies). Also learn about windowing where you taper the magnitude of your analog signal prior to taking the FFT and how that will effect the dynamic range and frequency resolution.